# get main colour of image and display that colour as a block

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap CSS. I have a bunch of icons which are all for different file types. Using JS I want to grab the most dominant colour of the image and use that colour as the colour of a bootstrap panel. How would I go about doing this?

NOTE: I have a 110 icons so easiest way possible thanks.

Comment: The [color thief](https://github.com/lokesh/color-thief) script does exactly this.

Comment: @TomWoodward thanks. I found the section where it gets the dominant colour and uses that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered by a comment. The answer is Color Thief

https://github.com/lokesh/color-thief